# Does Wall of Fire hurt people inside a Leomund’s Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

*Leomund’s Tiny Hut* says

> Creatures and objects⁠ within the dome when you cast this spell can move through it freely. All other creatures and objects⁠ are barred from passing through it. Spells and other magical Effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it. The Atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside.

*Wall of Fire* says

> When the wall appears, each creature within its area must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes 5d8 fire damage, or half as much damage on a successful save.
> One side of the wall, selected by you when you cast this spell, deals 5d8 fire damage to each creature that ends its turn within 10 feet of that side or inside the wall. A creature takes the same damage when it enters the wall for the first time on a turn or ends its turn there. The other side of the wall deals no damage.

Does *Tiny Hut* negate the magical heat of *Wall of Fire* or does it cook the adventurer?

Comment: Are you asking about the very unlikely scenario in which the wall is cast *inside* the hut? Are you specifically asking whether the "comfortable and dry" atmosphere of the hut negates the heat damage from being on the wrong side of the wall?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson only cast outside, should I clarify the title?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Magical effects can’t extend through the dome.

If the [*wall of fire*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=wall%20of%20fire) is on the outside, it doesn’t affect creatures on the inside because *[Leomund's tiny hut](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut)* says:

> Spells and other magical Effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it. The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside.

First, the damage from the wall of fire is a magical effect that cannot pass through the dome. Second, the dome doesn’t care about the temperature outside, “the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside.”

#### If for some reason you cast *wall of fire* while inside the dome, you’re in for a bad time.

This is a bad idea. The clause in the spell description about it being comfortable inside the dome only applies when you don’t change that by doing something like casting *wall of fire* inside the dome.

If you do happen to find yourself on the wrong side of a *wall of fire* that was cast inside the dome, you will take the damage.

Comment: One could argue that a *wall of fire* does not count as "weather" and that that section does not apply, but it doesn't matter since technically the wall of fire doesn't actually change the temperature of anything or it would say so. Spells not extending into the hut is the relevant part, the weather part seems unnecessary and borderline misleading.

Comment: @nwp: I feel like if you're parsing the rules finely enough to say that an ongoing fire doesn't affect the temperature *in the fire* which is *causing fire damage*, you've gone a bit too far.

Answer (score -6):

Leomund's tiny hut does create a space in the deep etherial plane. This means that everything inside the dome is gone from the outside world. There could be a cataclysmic event and these in the hut won't even notice it.
All living an dead matter can travel from inside of the dome to the place (i.e. prime material plane or other inner plane) the spell was cast on. So you could toss something like a bomb outside. If it is set off by a fuse - the result is up to the dm. I am not sure if fire could pass from inside to the outside.

Comment: "Leomund's tiny hut does create a space in the deep etherial plane" I dont see that in the spell description. Where did you get this information?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of *Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion*?